# Change class type using a TypeScript class decorator

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a TypeScript decorator that is able to modify the class it's applied to. After much experimentation I came to [the conclusion it is not yet possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), so I went a different route of using a plain function:

```
function component<P, T extends { props: P }, C extends { new(): T }>(cls: C) {
  return cls as C & P;
}

const Comp = component(class {
  props = {
    myOptionalString: undefined as string | undefined,
    myNumber: 5 as number,
  };

  static render(elem: typeof Comp) {
    const num: number = elem.myNumber;  // LINE 87
  }
});

const empty: typeof Comp | undefined = undefined;
const c = new Comp();
c.myOptionalString = 'hi';  // LINE 93
```

However this too does not work:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
(87,30): error TS2339: Property 'myNumber' does not exist on type 'typeof (Anonymous class) & {}'.

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
(93,3): error TS2339: Property 'myOptionalString' does not exist on type '(Anonymous class)'.
```

I'm basically trying to go the route of declaration merging via `&`, but it isn't working out so far.

Is there any way to mutate a class like this?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure it says `const Comp: comp<{etc}> = comp (class, etc.)`